# How do you enumerate over Error Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've looked around and have failed to find an answer to this.

What I am trying to do is print all the properties available in an Error object for error reporting. It may be impossible, but I would at least like to know why.

I have tried the following in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
try {
   throw new Error('Foo');
} catch (x) {
   console.log(Object.keys(x)); // []
   for (var i in x) console.log(i); // Prints nothing
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `console.dir(x);` to see what's inside (mostly the stack function) ?

Comment: What's the goal ? Are you adding properties ?

Comment: No. I need something to send back to the server for error reporting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enumerability of Error object keys varies amongst browsers. Your best bet is to use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x);
console.log(props);
for (var i=0; i<props.length; i++) console.log(x[props[i]]);
```

> I need something to send back to the server for error reporting.

I'd go with explicitly naming the properties I'm interested in, for example:

```
reportErrorBack( JSON.stringify({
    name: e.name, // on the Error.prototype
    message: e.message,
    stack: e.stacktrace
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

Do you know why you can't Enumerate over Error objects?